# issue when sorting a list in perl

Tags: list, perl, sorting, comparison

I have a list of strings which denote time values, i.e. 1us, 100ps, 10s, 7fs (microseconds, picoseconds, seconds, femtoseconds, etc). 
I need to sort the list in ascending order. To do that, I wrote a comparison routine which when given two strings, translates each string into the corresponding numerical value and compares them. Still, the list is not sorted correctly. After much debugging, I'm at a loss. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
   my %scales = ('fs'=>1e-15,'ps'=>1e-12,'ns'=>1e-9,'us'=>1e-6,'ms'=>1e-3,'s'=>1);
   my @times = ('1s','7ns','100ps','500ms','9us');
   my @stimes = sort bytime @times;
   sub bytime {

      my $op1 = $a;
      my $op2 = $b;
      $op1 =~ /\b(\d+)([munpf]*s)\b/;
      my $v1 = $1 * $scales{$2};
      $op2 =~ /\b(\d+)([munpf]*s)\b/;
      my $v2 = $1 * $scales{$2};
      return $v1 > $v2;
}

print "@times"."\n"."@stimes"."\n";
```

The result I get is:

1s 7ns 100ps 500ms 9us

100ps 7ns 500ms 1s 9us

which is clearly wrong, even though some sorting takes place. 
What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is on the line

```
return $v1 > $v2;
```

It will return 1 (true) if `$v1` is greater than `$v2` and `0` (false) in all other cases.

You want to instead use the numerical comparison operator `<=>`:

```
return $v1 <=> $v2;
```

which will return 1, 0 or -1 depending on the comparison result and will allow the sort to do its work correctly. (If you were dealing with strings instead of numbers, the operator would be `cmp`.)

Complete working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %scales = ('fs'=>1e-15,'ps'=>1e-12,'ns'=>1e-9,'us'=>1e-6,'ms'=>1e-3,'s'=>1);
my @times = ('1s','7ns','100ps','500ms','9us');
my @stimes = sort bytime @times;

sub bytime {
    my $op1 = $a;
    my $op2 = $b;
    $op1 =~ /\b(\d+)([munpf]*s)\b/;
    my $v1 = $1 * $scales{$2};
    $op2 =~ /\b(\d+)([munpf]*s)\b/;
    my $v2 = $1 * $scales{$2};
    return $v1 <=> $v2;
}

print "@times"."\n"."@stimes"."\n";
```

Output:

```
1s 7ns 100ps 500ms 9us
100ps 7ns 9us 500ms 1s
```

Comment: Thanks. When ">" would be used ?

Comment: You use normal comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `>=` and `<=` when you're just trying to find out whether that specific mathematical equation or inequation holds true. They return a true or false value.

Sort requires a three-valued comparison, where the same operator (or function) can return 1, 0 or -1 depending on the order of the two items. `$x <=> $y` is equal to `$x < $y ? -1 : ($x > $y ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: @Silvar answered well. But if speed is a concern, if maybe `@times` have thousands of elements, then you should also do the sort with a Schwartzian transform like this: `my @stimes = map $$_[0], sort {$$a[1]<=>$$b[1]} map [$_,convert($_)], @times;` with `sub convert { shift() =~ /\b(\d+)([munpf]*s)\b/ ? $1*$scales{$2} : die }`. This way, you will never convert the same number more than once. For more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform